# Remote with subhistory?

Tags: git

I have a private git repo with a long history. Now I'd like to add a public remote (github), without this long history, but starting from a specific tag (to hide all my beginner's mistakes, of course).

Starting from this, I'd like to develop on the private repository and sync only occasionaly.

I understand:

```
git remote add gh git://....
git push gh master
```

But that will push the whole history to the public repos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you should do:

```
git checkout --orphan empty-branch starting_tag
git commit -a -m "My first commit, yet everything is here"
```

It will create a new branch called empty-branch with no parent, with files from `starting_tag`. `starting_tag` is optional if you want to start from `HEAD`.

You can have a look at it in **git-checkout**(1) manpage.